# Signal Sigabrt when adding UITextField to code as an outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

As soon as I connect my 2 Text Fields to my code via "Control Drag" I can't get onto the view as it just quits to give me

> Thread 1: SIGNAL Sigabrt

The app runs but as soon as I open the page to where these text boxes are my app fails. I have the exact same setup on another app with the exact same code but am not getting the error my code is below:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ContactPage: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true;
    }

    var alert = UIAlertView()

    @IBOutlet var Name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Message: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func MakeCall(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.alert.title = "Calling Now..."
        self.alert.message = "You call will comence soon."
        self.alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        self.alert.show()
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://0394172817")!
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }

    @IBAction func email(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {

            let SubjectText = ""
            let MessageBody = ""
            let toRecipients = ["test@test.com"]

            let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mc.setSubject(SubjectText)
            mc.setMessageBody(MessageBody, isHTML: false)
            mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)

            self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            print("No email account found")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Submit(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {

            let SubjectText = Name
            let MessageBody = Message
            let toRecipients = ["test@test.com"]

            let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mc.setSubject(SubjectText.text!)
            mc.setMessageBody(MessageBody.text!, isHTML: false)
            mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)

            self.alert.title = "Registration Form"
            self.alert.message = "On this screen please press send."
            self.alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            self.alert.show()

            self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            print("No email account found")
        }
    }

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

        switch result.rawValue {

            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
                print("Mail Cancelled")
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
                print("Mail Saved")
            case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
                print("Mail Sent")
                self.alert.title = "Contact Form"
                self.alert.message = "Your form has been sent."
                self.alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                self.alert.show()
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
                print("Mail Failed")
                self.alert.title = "Contact Form"
                self.alert.message = "Your form failed to be sent. Please check your internet connection and try again"
                self.alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                self.alert.show()
            default:
                break
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowHome", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I will also add the error code:

```
2015-09-01 12:02:43.976 App Name[91111:2205337] Unknown class ContactPage in Interface Builder file. 
2015-09-01 12:02:44.078 App Name[91111:2205337] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7ff781d0a110> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Message.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051a99b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001071ffdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051a95f9 -[NSException raise] + 9
  3   Foundation                          0x0000000105573fdb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
  4   UIKit                               0x0000000105f9c418 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
  5   UIKit                               0x00000001061af2c7 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
  6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050ea590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
  7   UIKit                               0x00000001061adcaa -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
  8   UIKit                               0x0000000105fa2df4 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
  9   UIKit                               0x0000000105fa3720 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
  10  UIKit                               0x0000000105fa3a22 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
  11  UIKit                               0x0000000105fa4054 -[UIViewController view] + 27
  12  UIKit                               0x00000001066d36d2 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
  13  UIKit                               0x0000000105f74a4e -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133
  14  UIKit                               0x0000000105fb65ca -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3736
  15  UIKit                               0x0000000105fb94b3 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 343
  16  UIKit                               0x00000001064eee8b __67-[UIStoryboardModalSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 243
  17  UIKit                               0x00000001064dd523 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 449
  18  UIKit                               0x00000001064dd5ea -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
  19  UIKit                               0x0000000105e1f522 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
  20  UIKit                               0x0000000105f7ec06 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
  21  UIKit                               0x0000000105f7eeac -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 273
  22  UIKit                               0x0000000105f7e008 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
  23  UIKit                               0x0000000105e8715f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
  24  UIKit                               0x0000000105e87d4d -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
  25  UIKit                               0x0000000105e3c2ae -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
  26  UIKit                               0x0000000105e1836c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
  27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050d5b21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
  28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050cba4c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
  29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050caf03 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
  30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050ca918 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
  31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010acdcad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
  32  UIKit                               0x0000000105e1d99e UIApplicationMain + 171
  33  App Name                     0x0000000104fa749d main + 109
  34  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107d6492d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

If possible explain in detail as much as possible, I am very new to swift and Xcode and a little unsure on how everything runs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the Utilities Navigator while viewing the ContactPage file, is Target Membership selected correctly?

[image: Screenshot of Xcode Utilities Navigator]

If Target Membership isn't selected, the compiled binary won't include ContactPage.

If Target Membership is selected properly, in Interface Builder, double-check that Module is pointing to your app and not "None" underneath your class name.

[image: Interface Builder Utilities Navigator]

Lastly, clean your project using cmd+k.  This can resolve a couple broken dependencies, too.